# Transform discord.js bot into exe

Tags: node.js, discord.js, exe

I have a working discord bot, but I would like to compile it into a `.exe` file. How to do that?
I tried to use `pkg` and `nexe`, but both did not make it correctly. Nexe did not even start giving me some strange errors that I did not manage to fix after reading docs and some discussions on the Internet.
`Error: https://github.com/nexe/nexe/releases/download/v3.3.3/windows-x64-14.8.0 is not available, create it using the --build flag` and `Error: vcbuild.bat nosign release x64 exited with code: 1`.
The `pkg` worked better, I got and `exe` file, but it did not seem to work:
I have this code, where bot is my discord client.

```
bot.on('ready', () => 
{
    console.log(bot.guilds.cache.toJSON());
    bot.guilds.cache.forEach((gui) =>
    {
        console.log(gui.id + ' ' + gui.name + ' ' + gui.memberCount);
    });
    console.log('Bot started!');
});
```

It gives one server when I start it using `node index.js`, but does not give any if I execute the `exe` file created, though the bot becomes online.
My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "sth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "pkg": {
    "assets": [ "jsons/**/*", "config.json" ]
  },
  "bin": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.4.1"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does the bot start, but does not seem to be able to do anything? What have I missed?

Comment: Do you know if the code works when it is not an executable?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in the post, it works well.

Comment: What is working right now? When you run the exe does a console window appear that the `console.log`s could appear in?

Comment: When I start `.exe` I get the output of token in the console (just for testing). It is outside of all events, the 3-rd line of the code. And I get `bot started!` from `ready` event.

Comment: But the expected output also includes one server where the bot is. And it is outputted if I start the bot using `node index.js` but not if I use `exe`

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but `.toJSON()` is only meant for use on date objects. For other objects it's better to use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: This line gives the correct output when I start the bot from `.js` file, `exe` gives empty array (as like there are no servers). Anyway, the `.forEach` look should give the name of the server to the console, but it does not.

Comment: have you tried `console.log()`ing the `bot.guilds.cache` to see what is returned?

Comment: It returns an empty collection as like bot is on 0 guilds.

Comment: Ya at this point I really don't know what is going on. Hopefully someone else has an idea

Answer (score 0):

i don't know of an `.exe` file code you can use BUT you can use a `.bat` file and put it on desktop and create shortcuts or put it on `shell:startup` in that you will want to write this

```
@echo off
node "js file path"
```